Excluding dependencies from nuget inspector to analyze while doing a report for OSS review toolkit
I have a question regarding ORT OSS review toolkit (https://oss-review-toolkit.org/ort/).
I wanted to exclude .cpp files to be analyzed by nuget-inspector. I went through the documentation of oss review toolkit and found some ideas which I tried and failed.
Following are things I tried:
As the documentation the ORT tool suggests:
excludes:
paths:
- pattern: "[a-zA-Z].cpp"
reason: BUILD_TOOL_OF
comment: A comment further explaining why the path is excluded.
- pattern: "[a-zA-Z].vcxproj"
reason: BUILD_TOOL_OF
comment: A comment further explaining why the path is excluded.
excludes:
scopes:

pattern: "[a-zA-Z].Test.*"
reason: "TEST_TOOL_OF"
comment: >-
Licenses contained in this directory are used for testing and do not apply to the OSS Review Toolkit.
pattern: "[a-zA-Z].cpp"
reason: "TEST_TOOL_OF"
comment: >-
This directory contains example files with licenses that do not apply to the OSS Review Toolkit.
pattern: "[a-zA-Z].vcxproj"
reason: "TEST_TOOL_OF"
comment: >-
Licenses contained in this class are used for processing licenses and do not apply to the OSS Review Toolkit.

Tried with different glob expressions
[/a-zA-Z].vcxproj
.vcxproj
...
Tried adding a Nuget specific exclude in the analzyer configuration options
analyzer:
NuGet:
exclude:
- pattern: "**/.vcxproj"
- pattern: "**/*.cpp"
Tried adding fileRules as a anaylzer configuration option:
analyzer:
fileRules:
exclude:
- "/*.vcxproj"
- "/*.cpp"
I got this as an issue in report
IOException: Running 'nuget-inspector --with-details --verbose --project-file C:\Users...' failed with exit code -1
I expected not to have it.
